# to_timestamp in generated column

Tags: postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone, postgresql-14, generated-columns

I have a table in my DB (PstgreSQL 14) that is auto-generated by another software. This table contains a `t_stamp` column stored as a BIGINT. I need to use this `t_stamp`somewhere else as a TIMESTAMP data type.

I thought about creating a generated column that would simply be the `t_stamp` column, casted to the right type :

```
ALTER TABLE myTable 
ADD COLUMN cpt_timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE GENERATED ALWAYS AS to_timestamp(t_stamp/1000) STORED
```

And I get an error message :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to_timestamp"
LINE 2: ...tamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE GENERATED ALWAYS AS to_timesta...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 97
```

However, it works fine with a simple SELECT :

```
Select *, to_timestamp(t_stamp/1000) FROM my_table
```

Is it not possible to cast inside a generated query ?

Comment: You forgot the parentheses.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Where ?

Comment: The generation expression must be enclosed in parentheses. So: GENERATED ALWAYS AS **(** to_timestamp(t_stamp/1000) **)**